# PowerShell - Uppercase after a "Ternary" If Statement

Tags: string, powershell

What is the correct way to do this in PowerShell?

```powershell
$action = if ($args.Length > 0) { $args[0] } else { Read-Host 'Action' } #.ToUpper()
echo $action
```

The following seems like a code smell

```powershell
$action = if ($args.Length > 0) { $args[0] } else { Read-Host 'Action' }
$action = $action.ToUpper()
echo $action
```

Comment: I don't see how the first one is supposed to work. `#.ToUpper()` is a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first code block you have will almost work as written (you can assign the result of an if/else statement).

```powershell
$action = $(if ($args.Length -gt 0) { $args[0] } else { Read-Host 'Action' }).ToUpper()
```

You just need to use the `-gt` (greater than) operator instead of `>`, and wrap it in parentheses.

Comment: You need a `$` in front of the left parenthesis since if-else is a statement, not an expression.